# Gateaux Derivative of Fourier Transform/Characteristic Function

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

Suppose that $X$ is a square integrable random-variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.  It's characteristic function/Fourier transform is defined to be
$$
\mathfrak{F}[X](\gamma)\triangleq \int_{\omega \in \Omega}
 e^{-\gamma X(\omega)}
\mathbb{P}(d\omega)
.
$$

For any fixed $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, when is the map
\begin{align}
L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\\
X \mapsto \mathfrak{F}[X](\gamma),
\end{align}
Gateau differentiable (for what X)?  Moreover, what is its Gateau derivative?

Comment: Square integrability is not enough for your characteristic function to exist. This is rather called the moment generating function (with $-\gamma$ instead of $\gamma$).

Comment: On the subspace of $L^2$ on which the MFG exists, what can be said about it derivative then?